# Flutter map_view use map_view as widget

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dart, flutter

I would like to ask on how to show the map fullscreen using the function `MapView.Show` function on `map_view` dart framework which I couldn't implement as a `widget` in flutter. see my code below:

```
MapView showMap() { 
  return _mapView.show(new MapOptions(
    mapViewType: MapViewType.normal,
      initialCameraPosition:
        new CameraPosition(new Location(10.31264, 123.91139), 12.0),
    showUserLocation: true,
  ));
}
```

should be put inside the `child` in widget.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      height: double.infinity,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: showMap(), // surprisingly not working
    );
  }
```

I looked into tutorials on this implementation but it seems I haven't seen any liable sources on this implementation.  Does anyone knew how to implement this one?  Thanks!

**Note:** I want to implement as a fullscreen widget.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have to show the Map_View calling a function when an event happens (like when a button is pressed). It's not a Widget like a Text or a Padding.

If you want to open a fullscreen Map I'd suggest you to try, for example, this.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Container(
  color: Colors.red,
  height: double.infinity,
  width: double.infinity,
  child: Center(
    child: RaisedButton(
     onPressed: () => showMap(),
     child: Text("Click me!"),
   ),
  ), 
 );
}
```

Comment: yeah right but that isn't the case for me since I need to view the map in fullscreen,  the alternative way i can do is to use other flutter framework which is `google_map_flutter` from flutter team.